# Using a .delay() function before .css() manipulation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-animate

I have this:

```
var $ul = $(this).children("ul");
$ul.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
$ul.delay(1000).css("display", "none")
```

It's for my dropdown menu, and I want it to fade off before it disappears using the `display: none;` CSS property. However, it appears that the `.delay()` cannot be used on the `.css()`; it doesn't work, the `$ul` just disappears right away.

I can't use `$ul.animate({opacity: 0, display: "none"}, 1000);` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter to [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is a callback that's called when the animation is complete, so you can use it like so:

```
$ul.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() { 
    $(this).css("display", "none")
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Like [codeka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241462/codeka) said the callback is the correct approach here, but there are some shortcut methods built in you can use to simplify it further, [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), like this:

```
$ul.fadeOut(1000, function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to use the `.animate()`. Call it personal preference, if you will =)

Comment: @Fabian if you prefer twice the bytes knock yourself out :)  I prefer to take advantage of what's there...the client's already downloaded these functions, might as well save them more bandwidth by using them :)